# jsPDF-CustomFonts-support is not working with Bangla font I am using jspdf- autotable

Tags: jspdf

I am trying to generate PDF using jsPDF it's working well but the problem with Bangla font is there any way to solve this problem? Font sourced from  https://www.omicronlab.com/bangla-fonts.html

[image]m/JAwvr.png